# Is Rails good to build web interfaces for programs in languages other than Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say, I want to create a web interface for a program or application written in a different language other than Ruby, maybe, Java or C. Is using Rails still a good option ? If so, can anyone give me sources(links to tutorials or books) which I can refer to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

There are ports of rails to other languages and rails-like things for other languages.  You would use one of those ports, not Ruby on Rails -- what is normally referred to as "Rails" is a framework for ruby and can't easily be used with other languages.

For C, I'm not sure what you'd do, but probably not a rails-like thing (not sure how serious that question is).

For Java, there are light, MVC-style, frameworks that aren't exactly Rails, but more common.  Look into Spring and Hibernate.  There are other choices, though.

Comment: Rails internally uses many of Ruby's features such as blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to do that, but if you want a dynamically typed language, with an MVC framework attached you could do worse than try [Grails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grails_(framework)), which is built on Groovy, which is in turn built on Java.

You get the scaffolding of Rails, with an ORM built in, and the advantages of groovy over java, namely closures. Better still, most Java code will work with [Groovy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_(programming_language)), so it's great if you know Java already, but want to dabble a bit with a dynamically typed language.

Obviously being java, it's on the JVM.